# Attempting to use Sanity.io CLI results in 'zsh: command not found'

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, zsh, oh-my-zsh, sanity

I am having a problem running Sanity's CLI. I have installed the CLI with `npm install -g @sanity/cli` which works without a problem, and everything is installed correctly (as far as I can tell).

However, trying to use any of their CLI instructions, such as `sanity init`, I get this error message:

```
zsh: command not found: sanity
```

I am using npm version 6.14.11 and node version v14.16.0.

I've also been noticing a few random commands return the same `zsh: command not found` for various packages.

Comment: When you run `sanity --version` what happens? 
I would probably suggest `npm uninstall -g @sanity/cli` then running `npm install -g @sanity/cli` again. Once you've done that, check your global install with `npm -g ls @sanity/cli`

Comment: Running `sanity --version` returns the same `zsh: command not found: sanity` error. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling and am getting the same issue. 

When I reinstalled it, I did get the version: @sanity/cli@2.6.0

Comment: @DavisKane : Provide the complete PATH to `sanity`. Alternatively, make sure that the directory containing the _sanity_ executable is in your `PATH`.

Comment: @DavisKane : See [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Check-Path-in-Unix) for a detailed treatment of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `npx` instead of directly typing sanity manage

after so many trials it worked for me

```bash
npx sanity manage
```

Comment: Tried it on my mac and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@user1934428 is right.

I just change in the command "sanity ..." to "usr/local/Cellar/node/16.3.0/lib/node_modules/@sanity/cli/bin/sanity ..." and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my mac which was caused by not installing sanity globally.

Go to your terminal and enter:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

Enter your password then install sanity globally

```
npm install -g ng
```

This should solve the issue and sanity commands should work too.

Answer (score -1):

with npx it works

```
npx @sanity/cli init
```